# How can I avoid this "inconvenience" on Eval?

Tags: c#, .net, repeater

If I am on a Repeater, I have a code like this:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RepeaterComunicati">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="CancellaComunicazione-<%#Eval("COID").ToString()%>" runat="server" onclick="cmdCancellaComunicazione_Click">
             Hello
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

the "inconvenience" is the I need to remember the "name" of my field of the Item.

If I am on a For Each, Visual Studio Help me with the name. Somethings like `item.COID` is immediate.

Is it a different way on Eval? Or I need to watch my object every time and COPY/PASTE name of the field, putting them on Eval statment?

Comment: MVC solved this 'issue' ;p

Comment: why MVC ? if you are using asp.net 4.5  then you will get Model Type. strongly typed binding in declaration :) http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/09/02/strongly-typed-data-controls-asp-net-vnext-series.aspx

Comment: Damn, I'm using the 4 version. Need an update I think. Thank you Rave to write out that trick!

Comment: @Ravi: Cool, didn't know about them .

Comment: @Ravi: how can that article be 2011/09/02 old when .NET 4.5 is released about august 2012?

Comment: @markzzz author is Scott GU :) so he may used the preview  build :) to encourage the community to use vNext

Comment: Uhm, i'm a bit odd! I don't know what is vNext :P What is? A plugin?

Answer (score 0):

As you may have noticed those are strings there. This means that the framework will be using reflection instead of something type safe to access that property.

Unfortunately this means you can't get autocomplete in the strings and you will be "inconvenienced" a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Copy a snippet of code and comment it out in your aspx page. This way you can simply copy and paste it where you need it.